# Why does the type cast of malloc in C have the * symbol on the right and not on the left?

Tags: c, syntax, casting, malloc

In C, a void pointer is declared, usually, like this:

```
int a = 10; 
char b = 'x'; 
  
void *p = &a;  // void pointer holds address of int 'a' 
p = &b; // void pointer holds address of char 'b'
```

However, the syntax of malloc in C is like this:

```
ptr = (cast-type*) malloc(byte-size)
```

What I can't understand is why the "*" symbol in the "cast-type" section of the code above is on the right. I would assume the correct way of writing the same line of code would be like this:

```
ptr = (*cast-type) malloc(byte-size)
```

That's because when declaring a pointer the "*" is on the left, not on the right.

What's the problem with my reasoning?

Comment: Aside: please see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Because that is the syntax: look at the way you defined `void *p`. The `*` is on the right of the *type* and you could have defined `void* p` although I prefer the first.

Comment: the actual syntax for `malloc()` in C is: `void *malloc(size_t size);`  I suspect your confusing C with C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That's because when declaring a pointer the "*" is on the left, not on the right.

The `*` is on the right *of the type name*. In `void *p = &a;` type is `void *`, a void pointer. It is on the left of the thing it's being applied to, the variable `p`.

In `ptr = (cast-type*) malloc(byte-size)` the type is `cast-type *`, the `*` is to the right of the type name. The cast is on the left of the thing being cast, the call to malloc, like an adjective.

[*I do find it odd that we write `type *variable`, which makes it seem like the `*` is part of the `variable` rather than `type* variable` which puts the `*` with the type.*]

Comment: Yes, but when you write `type* variable, anothervar;` only `variable` is a pointer. Writing `type *variable, anothervar;` makes it clear.

Comment: *I do find it odd that we write `type *variable`, which makes it seem like the `*` is part of the variable rather than `type* variable` which puts the `*` with the type.*  Because the `*` ***IS*** with the variable.  `int* a, b` makes `b` an `int`, ***NOT*** an `int *`.

Comment: @Schwern: There are good reasons to declare variables separately, but working around bad practice isn’t one of them.  `*` is part of the declarator, period.  Pretending it isn’t leads to confusion and inconsistency.  A declaration like `int* a[10];` is schizophrenic.  And it doesn’t work for pointers to arrays or pointers to functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` indirection operator is a *unary* operator, meaning its operand is to the right of the operator, as in `*p`.

C declarations are broken into two major sections - a sequence of declaration specifiers (type specifiers, storage class specifiers, type qualifiers, etc.) followed by a comma-separated list of declarators.  A declarator introduces the name of the thing being declared, along with information about that thing’s array-ness, pointer-ness, and function-ness.  In the declaration statement

```
int a[10], *p, f(void);
```

the declaration specifier is `int` and the declarators are `a[10]`, `*p`, and `f(void)`.  Note that the `*` is bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.  Because it’s a unary operator and token on its own, you don’t need whitespace to separate the type specifier from the identifier - all of

```
int *p;
int* p;
int*p;
int     *      p;
```

are equally valid, and all are interpreted as `int (*p);` - the operand of `*` is always `p`, not `int` or any other type specifier<sup>1</sup>.

The type of `a` is "10-element array of `int`", which is fully specified by the combination of the `int` type specifier and by the `[10]` in the declarator.  Similarly the type of `p` is "pointer to `int`", which again is fully specified by the combination of the type specifier and the `*` operator in the declarator.  And the type of `f` is "function returning `int`" by the same reasoning.

This is key - there is no type specifier for pointer, array, or function types - they can only be specified by a *combination* of one or more declaration specifiers and a declarator.

So how do we specify pointer types (or array or function types) in a cast?  Basically, we write a declaration composed of declaration specifiers and a declarator, but with no identifier.  If we want to cast something as a pointer to `int`, we write it as a regular pointer declaration with an unnamed variable - `(int *)`.

---

1. This is why I’m not fond of the C++ convention of writing pointer declarations as `T* p;`; it doesn’t follow the syntax, and it’s inconsistent - a declaration like `int* a[N];` is schizophrenic.  It also introduces confusion when you write something like `T* p, q;` because it looks like you intend to declare both `p` and `q` as pointers, but only `p` is.